# Is SSDT 2015 backwards compatible with previous VS versions?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, backwards-compatibility

Unfortunately when I try to search around this topic, I'm swamped by the fact that they introduced backwards compatibility with previous *SQL* versions, but I want to know if there are any backwards compatibility issues with previous *Visual Studio* versions.

For example, if I am working on a SQL 2014 SSIS project in VS 2015, but my co-worker is working on the same SSIS project in VS 2013, are there any issues we might/will come across?

Answer (score 1):

You might run into some small merge issues w/ the version that generated the project, but I don't think you'll hit anything else if you're working on the same files. I worked on some SSRS reports back when this was in beta and didn't have any issues with a co-worker who was not on VS 2015.  Pretty sure we went through something similar with SSIS.  As long as you don't use any features specific to SSIS in SQL 2016, you should be fine.

Should be easy enough to test in a branch.  Have your coworker start a file, you work on it, pass it back to him, then back again.  Do the same thing starting with VS 2015 and passing it back and forth.  You should know and prove pretty quickly whether it will give you any issues.  I don't expect any based on my experiences.

Comment: Thanks for the response :) from what I've seen so far it adds a couple of lines to the project file, which are then trimmed out when it opens in 2013. So it might cause clutter in code reviews but otherwise doesn't seem to be causing any actual issues so far - haven't tried serious development yet though.